# Vim encoding issue with danish characters æøå

Tags: vim, character-encoding, input

When trying to input danish characters æøå into vim, I suddenly get "æ ø å " and then the questionmark blocks on reopening. The same goes for files saved in other editors and reopened in vim. I have set my encoding to utf-8 in my vimrc, and experience no issues in other editors. Are there other encoding options I should be aware of than

> :set encoding

?

Comment: What `fileencoding` is being set when you open the file?

Comment: I have the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

You may have to enable detection for UTF-8 by setting `fileencodings`:

```
set fileencodings=ucs-bom,utf-8,cp1257,latin1
```

(note: *fileencoding* is current, *fileencoding**s*** is list of encodings to try.)

Comment: I have the same problem as Santeh. Unfortunately your solution didn't work for me.

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same problem, and found the cause of it to be that I had installed the auto-pairs plugin (plugin/auto-pairs.vim). Once I removed that, problem disappeard. Guess auto-pairs doesn't like æøå.